# merge multiple excel into single excel workbook with different columns in every excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I have to merge multiple excel into single excel workbook. Suppose I have 3 excel sheets.

ExcelA.xls -- it contains 3 columns A, B, C

ExcelB.xls -- it contains 4 Columns B, D, E, F

ExcelC.xls -- it contains 3 Columns A, C, D

Now my ExcelFinal.xls should contain as A, B, C, D, E, F always, the data mapping against the columns should be intact always.
Also the column name should be not repeated in rows. We need to achieve this using VB script.

Speedy help will be highly appreciated!

thanks!
Alok

Comment: 1. What have tried - share your code/research?; 2. Your tags are wrong. VBA <> VB script. Are you looking for a solution in VBA or VB script?

Comment: `Speedy help will be highly appreciated` Well the speed of which you receive a good answer is inversely proportional to the speed you ask your question. Questions asked without doing research and any attempt to solve it often get no reply, down voted and closed.

Comment: I am sorry for wrong tag!
I need VB Script.

Comment: I have arrived at this script but it is mismatching the columns:

Comment: `Speedy help will be highly appreciated!` Love it :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
Sub CopyData()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range
Dim columnValues, sourceWorksheet, sourceWorkbook, targetWorkheet, targetWorkbook As String
Dim currentWorkbook, templateWorksheet, reference As String

 sourceWorkbook = "Data.xlsx"
 sourceWorksheet = "data"
 targetWorkbook = "DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm"
 targetWorkheet = "data"
 templateWorksheet = "template"

' For 1st column
Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbook)
currentWorkbook.Sheets(templateWorksheet).Activate
reference = "A4"
columnValues = Range(reference).value

If columnValues <> " " Then

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(columnValues)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Columns("A")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If


' For 2nd column
Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbook)
currentWorkbook.Sheets(templateWorksheet).Activate
reference = "B4"
columnValues = Range(reference).value

If columnValues <> " " Then

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(columnValues)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Columns("B")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If


' For 3rd column
Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbook)
currentWorkbook.Sheets(templateWorksheet).Activate
reference = "C4"
columnValues = Range(reference).value

If columnValues <> " " Then

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(columnValues)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Columns("C")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If

' For 4th column
Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbook)
currentWorkbook.Sheets(templateWorksheet).Activate
reference = "D4"
columnValues = Range(reference).value

If columnValues <> " " Then

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(columnValues)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Columns("D")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If

' For 5th column
Set currentWorkbook = Workbooks(targetWorkbook)
currentWorkbook.Sheets(templateWorksheet).Activate
reference = "E4"
columnValues = Range(reference).value

If columnValues <> " " Then

    Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns(columnValues)
    Set targetColumn = Workbooks("DynamicColumnsTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("data").Columns("E")
    sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? Or is this what you have tried  but didn't work? If it's not an answer, please use the **edit** link on your question and place this there, and then delete this not an answer. Thanks.